# C++ - How to change/decrement value in file?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, struct

My friend and I have this problem, where we want to decrement or change value of number in file, but we need to use structures to do it. Is that even possible in C++ or it is not? Sorry, if it is not I am beginner in C++

Here is the input file

```
50
60
```

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct number
{
    int numberChange;
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("value.txt");
    number arr[100];
    int numberOfnumbers;
    while (file >> arr[numberOfnumbers].numberChange)
    {
        numberOfnumbers++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfnumbers; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i].numberChange << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The console output is this

```
50
60
```

I want to change the value of the first number `50` to like `45` but I do not know how to do that

Comment: You can overwrite characters in a file, as long as the result is the same length.  For example, if you overwrite `50` with `1000`, you could overwrite the next characters in the file.

Comment: Read in the data, make the change and write a new file.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector` when reading data from a file.  Arrays can overflow; or you may wasting space (e.g. allocating 100 slots when there are only 3 data).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes I know but this is just for the example purposes. Thanks for the advice, anyway

Comment: ***Is that even possible in C++ or it is not?*** Of course its possible to use a struct or class to hold the data for your array.  And change values in the data. And then write the data back to a file. `struct MyData {std::vector <int> data;};`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in your first `while` loop you save whatever numbers you get in the file into the array of type `number`. You can treat this like any normal array now. You already know the number of elements in the array so you can simply index the array like `arr[N]` where N is any number less than `numberOfnumbers`. Then you can operate on any number in the array in the way you desire. For the example that you provided changing 50 to 45, after the `while` loop do `arr[0].numberChange = 45;`. After changing the data, you can overwrite what was originally in the file with your new numbers.